# Hibernate entity version not incremented but database version field is

Tags: java, hibernate, entity, version

I am not sure what to do about the following:

1. I create an entity on the client, send it to the server, merge and call `saveOrUpdate`. The merged entity is returned to the client;
2. The entity is then modified on the client, sent to the server and `saveOrUpdate` is called again. The method exits but the entity does not have its `version` number updated and it is sent to the client. The version number of the entity is now out of sync with the database. **The entities `version` field in the database is correctly updated**;
3. The entity is deleted from its parent collection but because the `equals()` method uses the `version` field it fails and does not remove the entity. Either that or I get an `OptimisticLockException` while updating the entity again.

Is this normal behaviour for Hibernate?

1. If not, what could be causing it?
2. If so then must I manually update the version field of every modified entity before returning it to the client?

**Service class**

```
public List<HtDayEntry> deleteHtDayEntry(String clientVersion,
        @Lazy HtDayEntry htDayEntryToDelete, List<HtDayEntry> modifiedHtDayEntries)
        throws ClientServerVersionMismatchException {
    compareClientServerVersion(clientVersion);
    htDayEntryToDelete = (HtDayEntry) htDayEntryDao.merge(htDayEntryToDelete);
    // START: remove from the other side of the relationships
    HtDay htDay = htDayEntryToDelete.getHtDay();
    htDay.getHtDayEntries().remove(htDayEntryToDelete);
    HtDayEntryType htDayEntryType = htDayEntryToDelete.getHtDayEntryType();
    htDayEntryType.getHtDayEntries().remove(htDayEntryToDelete);
    for (HtNote htNote : htDayEntryToDelete.getHtNotes()) {
        htNote.setHtDayEntry(null);
    }
    // END: remove from the other side of the relationships
    htDayEntryDao.delete(htDayEntryToDelete);
    if (isHtDayEmpty(htDay)) {
        htDayDao.delete(htDay);
    }
    if (modifiedHtDayEntries != null) {
        HtDayEntry modifiedHtDayEntry;
        ListIterator iterator = modifiedHtDayEntries.listIterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            modifiedHtDayEntry = (HtDayEntry) iterator.next();
            modifiedHtDayEntry = (HtDayEntry) htDayEntryDao.merge(modifiedHtDayEntry);
            htDayEntryDao.saveOrUpdate(modifiedHtDayEntry);
            // START: must manually update the version field, I have no idea why
            modifiedHtDayEntry.setVersion(modifiedHtDayEntry.getVersion() + 1);
            iterator.set(modifiedHtDayEntry); // Update the modifiedHtDayEntry in the iterator so that the new version number can be returned
            // END: must manually update the version field, I have no idea why
        }
    }
    return modifiedHtDayEntries;
}
```

**HtDayEntryDao**

```
public void saveOrUpdate(Object object) throws HibernateException {
    getSession().saveOrUpdate(object);
}
```

**Entity** (methods in superclass)

```
private long version;

@Version
@Column(name = "version")
public Long getVersion() {
    return version;
}

public void setVersion(Long version) {
    this.version = version;
}
```

Comment: Which one do you return to the client, the one you passed to merging or the result of merging?

Comment: I updated the code in the Service Class to show that it is the merged entity that is being returned to the client.

Comment: You should not increment it manually. Hibernate does it during flushing automatically. What is the client here? I mean, is it possible that you serialize/marshal the entities before the transaction is ended (thus before flush is executed)?

Comment: The client is a Flex application. 

I have updated the service method to show it as it actually is. I don't think that serialization is occuring before  `flush` is called. 

I can see that in other parts of the client code the parent is sent and saved in order to persist the child. In that case the version number is automatically incremented. However that isn't occurring when I send the entity that I want to persist directly.

Comment: I also tried calling `flush` manually and put a breakpoint on the following line. The version number did not increase.

Comment: What's in `htDayEntryDao.saveOrUpdate`?

Comment: It is just a pass through to: `getSession().saveOrUpdate(object)`. 

I am wondering if this is not a Hibernate problem at all but something to do with the GraniteDS framework in the Flex client that is merging the entities. GraniteDS merges the incoming entity with the local client entity based upon an incremented `version` number. That said manually incrementing the `version` number does cause the client side merge to occur and looking at the object returned from the server it does not have that increment unless done manually. To me it therefore still looks like a Hibernate  issue.